# Pull specific data from CSV

Tags: import, rest-api, csv

I'm building a website, and client has specific request. Open source app has .csv file providing bunch of data. They want to pull some fields from that csv and to place it in on wordpress website.

Is it possible to do something like that? They want to automate the process where I'll place the link to CSV, select which fields it will pull and then those fields are shown on the website. Also when the CSV is updated, data will also be updated.

Is it possible to something like that?

Comment: Yeah it's possible, but you're gonna need to be *way* more specific to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the client to upload csv file. After upload you can read csv file with a php function (maybe [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.fgetcsv.php)) and put columns and rows to table (maybe with [dataTables](https://datatables.net/) jQuery plugin).

If you let the user to edit table, you can use these information for create a `form`

After that you can use `update_post_meta` or another function for that.